# Access VBA to Copy Folders from Server to Desktop - FIle Path of Folders listed in query

Tags: vba, ms-access, recordset, filesystemobject

Help! I can't get my VBA to work and your help is appreciated!

-Need to copy a set of folders from server to desktop.
-Folders on the server are for each item by model number.
-Within Access database, items can be selected with a checkbox within the Item table.
-"qFilter_LibrarySearchResults" is a query of the selected items. The query contains a field, "Location" which is a text field, and the text is the file path to the item's folder on the server.

I know VERY VERY little about VBA. I am attempting to use a form to select the items I need, then click a VBA controlled button to copy the needed folders from the server to my desktop so I can work with these items more easily.

Within my VBA I have created a dao recordset from the query field "Location" and then tried to use Scripting.FileSystemObject to copy the folder from A to B. But it doesn't work and my recordset only returns NOTHING.

```
Private Sub Command62_Click()

Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb

Dim rst As dao.Recordset
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select Location From qFilter_LibrarySearchResults")

Dim objFSO As New FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

objFSO.copyFolder Location, "C:\Users\drawingcoordinator\Desktop\"

Do While Not rst.EOF
rst.MoveNext
Loop

End Sub
```

The above is supposed to create a record set of file paths (Location) for the selected items, and then move through the list copying one folder after the another to my desktop, then stop at the end of the list.

When I click the button in my form to run the VBA I get

> Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument.

When I attempt to Debug, the line "objFSO.copyFolder Location, `"C:\Users\drawingcoordinator\Desktop\"` is highlighted yellow and hovering over "location" shows Location=Empty.

Comment: you dont assign a value to location in any place...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The copy operation must be inside the loop (between the lines `Do While ...` and `rst.MoveNext`) to be repeated for every location in the recordset.

Then you must use the field of the recordset. I.e., `rst!Location` instead of simply `Location` which must be some variable whose declaration I do not see (have you set [`Option Explicit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement) on top of the code module? Which I strongly recommend.).

```vb
Private Sub Command62_Click()
    Dim db As Database
    Set db = CurrentDb
    
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select Location From qFilter_LibrarySearchResults")
    
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Do While Not rst.EOF
        objFSO.copyFolder rst!Location, "C:\Users\drawingcoordinator\Desktop\"
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
End Sub
```

Also, I recommend to rename the buttons before you create the Click Subroutine, so that you get speaking names. E.g. for a button named `CopyFoldersCommand` you get a `Sub` named `CopyFoldersCommand_Click` which is more readable than `Command62_Click`.

Another issue is that you created the `FileSystemObject` twice. Once with `New FileSystemObject` and once with `CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`. It does not create an error but is nonsensical.

Better declare the variable with `Dim objFSO As Object` and then create the object with `CreateObject`. This has the advantage that the `Scripting` library needs not to be referenced which increases the reliability of the application.

Comment: Thanks for the help!! It now copies the first folder in the record set but does not move down the list (of which I have two for testing purposes).

Comment: Are you sure? The code is there for loop. Set a breakpoint on the rst.MoveNext line and step through code.

Comment: I am not familiar with the [CopyFolder method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/copyfolder-method), but assume that it copies all of the source files and sub-folders into the same destination folder. so, you will see only one destination.

Comment: I've researched the CopyFolder method and once I get it coded correctly, what it's supposed to do is copy the folder identified by the FROM file path and paste it to the TO file path. Then it will loop to the next file path then the next, to the end of the list (contained in the record set). I think it's almost there and your response above is the reason why so from amatuer to expert, thank you very much!